# Finding the center of a group with MAGMA

Tags: group-theory

Given a finitely presented group $G = \langle S | R \rangle$, is there a command in MAGMA that computes the center of G ?

Comment: If Center() won't work on G, you can use one of the functions available to covert G into a group of a type on which Center() will work.

Comment: This is unlikely to be possible unless $G$ is finite, in which case you should use a command like CosetImage to convert it to a group of permutations.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

> Y:=permutationGroup(G):
>
> Centre(Y);